# New line in Title of an org-mode exported html document

Tags: org-mode, html, org-export

I use org-mode to document stuff and usually export it to pdf (via latex) and html.

If the `\\` characters are at the **end** of a line, it forces a newline character when exporting to both pdf and html.

But I would like to know how to force a newline character **in-between** a line when exporting to html. It would be helpful to have this solution so that I can have multi-line titles in html exports too.

Example:

```
#+TITLE: First Line of Title \\ Second Line of Title
```

The above exports to 2 lines in pdf export but the `\\` characters are retained in html export (as they are not at the end of the line).

How can I format the title so that multi line titles export fine in both formats?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Org mode 8 no longer accepts LaTeX characters like that. The correct way to do it is embed export snippets in the title:

```
#+TITLE: Foo @@latex:\\@@ Bar
```

I assume therefore that if you want to export newlines in both LaTeX and HTML, the code might have to look like this:

```
#+TITLE: Foo @@latex:\\@@ @@html:<br>@@ Bar
```

Source: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-09/msg00466.html

If such newline characters are needed to be added at multiple places in the document, replacing this verbose `@@latex:\\@@ @@html:<br>@@` string with an org mode `MACRO` would be better suited.

A MACRO definition like below can be placed at the top of the document or in a common "org config" file that's included in your org documents:

```
#+MACRO: NEWLINE @@latex:\\@@ @@html:<br>@@
```

The MACRO can then be used for formatting the title as below:

```
#+TITLE: Foo {{{NEWLINE}}} Bar
```

The advantages of using the MACRO approach are:

- The org mode document is easier to read
- If the need arises to change the definition of `{{{NEWLINE}}}` to support a new export format, then that change needs to be done at just one place.

Example:

```
#+MACRO: NEWLINE @@latex:\\@@ @@html:<br>@@ @@ascii:|@@
```

*NOTE: `@@ascii:|@@` won't insert a newline in ascii exports; it will simply place the pipe character `|` wherever `{{{NEWLINE}}}` was used in the org doc.*

Finally, the `#+SUBTITLE` keyword may also help.

Comment: A related question: Would you know how to convey a newline for ascii exports? `@@ascii:\n@@` doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. I'd guess a feature request is needed to get this implemented.

Comment: You mean the newlines in ascii don't work, correct? Otherwise your solution works for html and pdf exports. When newlines for ascii is supported, I simply have to update the NEWLINE macro.

Comment: Clarification (spelled out in the mailing list link): "no longer accepts LaTeX characters like that" applies to the fields `AUTHOR`, `TITLE` and `DATE`, not org-mode in general.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure there wouldn't be any unwanted side effects, but the following might work

```
(push (cons "\\\\\\\\" "<br />") org-html-special-string-regexps)
```

Kinda lucky that the list of special string expansions is extensible in the HTML exporter, because it's not in the LaTeX exporter...