# How to add new markup to org-mode HTML export?

Tags: org-mode, html

I would like to add a markup to org-mode, to simplify adding `<audio>` HTML tags. Like other inline markup:

```
In Thai, /sabai dee mai/ is pronounced as [audio:assets/sabai.mp3]
```

Which would export as:

```
<p>In Thai, <i>sabai dee mai</i> is pronounced as <audio src="assets/sabai.mp3"></audio></p>
```

I looked at `org.el` and `ox-html.el` to perhaps just copy how bold and such inline markup works, but I don't see how the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Org is extremely versatile when it comes to defining links, so they're probably your best bet. For that you need the [`org-add-link-type`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-add-link-type) function.

```
(org-add-link-type "audio" #'ignore #'endless/export-audio-link)
```

The second argument is telling org you don't care about opening `audio` links for now, and the third argument says how to export them to html. Use the following example function, or improve it to your needs.

```
(defun endless/export-audio-link (path desc format)
  "Export org audio links to hmtl."
  (cl-case format
    (html (format "<audio src=\"%s\">%s</audio>" path (or desc "")))
    (latex (format "(HOW DO I EXPORT AUDIO TO LATEX? \"%s\")" path))))
```

---

With the above configuration, the links

```
[[audio:file.mp3][description]]
[[audio:file-2.mp3]]
```

would export to

```
<audio src="file.mp3">description</audio>
<audio src="file-2.mp3"></audio>
```

---

[This post](http://endlessparentheses.com/use-org-mode-links-for-absolutely-anything.html) also explains how you can define a way to actually open these audio links inside `org-mode` (by using the second argument).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [org-mode macro replacement](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html) to achieve this.

A macro called `AUDIO` can be defined as below

```
#+MACRO AUDIO @@html:<audio src="$1"></audio>@@
```

Using your example, here is what its usage will look like:

```
In Thai, /sabai dee mai/ is pronounced as {{{AUDIO(assets/sabai.mp3)}}}
```

which would export to html as:

```
<p>In Thai, <i>sabai dee mai</i> is pronounced as <audio src="assets/sabai.mp3"></audio></p>
```

Comment: Another example of org-mode macro usage for a different application: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/261/115

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://endlessparentheses.com/inserting-the-kbd-tag-in-org-mode.html) describes you can alter existing markup to produce any kind of tag you want. I'm not aware of any way of defining *new* markup with this, but, since `~` and `=` are redundant when exporting to html, you can change one of the two while still using the other as `<code>`.

The following snippet should turn `~sabai.mp3~` into `<audio src="sabai.mp3"></audio>` when exporting.

```
(eval-after-load 'ox-html
  '(push '(code . "<audio src="%s"></audio>") org-html-text-markup-alist))
```

And the following will do the same with `=sabai.mp3=` instead.

```
(eval-after-load 'ox-html
  '(push '(verbatim . "<audio src="%s"></audio>") org-html-text-markup-alist))
```