# How do I insert multiple line breaks in org-mode when exporting to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to emphasize a particular bit of text that contains a poem. The way I'm trying to do that is by inserting multiple line breaks

```
something \\ \\ \\ poem
```

However in html it renders the same way

> something \ \ \ poem

How do I insert multiple line breaks to emphasize a piece of text in org mode

Comment: are you aware of `#+verse` environment? I.e. `#+begin_verse` ... `#+end_verse`?

Comment: See the solution to [this emacs SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/255/115).. use of a custom `NEWLINE` macro.

Comment: ^^ I have used that but somehow It doesn't give the spacing I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\\` works only in LaTeX.

Try this:

```org
something
#+HTML: <br>
#+HTML: <br>
#+HTML: <br>
poem
```

---

An even better solution that would work for different exports would be to define your own `NEWLINE` macro. [[Source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/261/115)].

```org
#+MACRO: NEWLINE @@latex:\\@@ @@html:<br>@@ @@ascii:|@@
something {{{NEWLINE}}}{{{NEWLINE}}}{{{NEWLINE}}}
poem
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check your setting of `org-export-preserve-breaks` value.
The following is in-buffer setting of the variable.

```org
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
```

The following code become enabled in ox-html.el when the variable is t.

```org
(setq output
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\(\\\\\\\\\\)?[ \t]*\n"
     (concat (org-html-close-tag "br" nil info) "\n") output))
```

This means \\ at end of line only export to <br>.

Therefore,

```org
something \\
\\
\\
poem
```

will export to:

```org
something<br>
<br>
<br>
poem
```

Please see https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

what about the followings both to LaTeX and HTML.

```
something \\
\\
\\
poem
```

Comment: This does not work it has the same problem

Comment: Oh, my! I don't know why, but both of newline in LaTeX, and <br> in HTML are exported and handled well in my Mac OS X environment, by just putting "\\". I thought this is so natural, which is not, and I can't figure it out yet.